# Create a submit button from a event

Tags: javascript, php, html

I would like to create a submit button on a element which appear when a click on a submit button

Step 1 : I am on 'index.php' and I click on a button for start a comment box, which called by a java script fonction and which come from a 'comment.php'

Step 2 : I would like to insert a submit button on the called element (like comment button).

Page 1

```js
function showcomment(question_ID) {
  var request;
  try {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } catch (tryMicrosoft) {
    try {
      request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (otherMicrosoft) {
      try {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (failed) {
        request = null;
      }
    }
  }
  var php = "./core/show-comment.php";
  var comment_content = document.getElementById("comment_content_" + question_ID).value;
  var vars = "comment_content=" + comment_content + "&user_ID=" + user_ID + "&question_ID=" + question_ID;
  request.open("POST", php, true);

  request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      var return_data = request.responseText;
      document.getElementById(question_ID).innerHTML = return_data;
    }
  }

  request.send(vars);
}
```

```html
<input type='submit' name='comment' value='show comment' onclick='fonction()'>
```

Page 2

```html
<type="submit" name="like">

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['like']))
    {
     $query_new_like = "UPDATE comments SET approval_rate = approval_rate +1 WHERE comment_ID = '$comment_ID'" ;
    mysqli_query ($connect,$query_new_like) ;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: post your function code

Comment: It's done Bhavik

Comment: pass the input button from show_comment.php

Comment: I try but the comment appear with a fetch_array. And i can't put a submit button near each comment without array

Comment: after fetch array write your button code

Comment: It's work but the without the page second page, we don't have a dynamique comment box